# FlipBoard with core animation only

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, flipboard

i would like to do a flipboard of many view (not image but uiview) by using only Core Animation, not OpenGL. i saw many exemple of flip but they involve only image flip and capture of image layer. like here: https://github.com/brow/leaves
some can help me please.

Answer (score 3):

I found this [Github project called FlipView](https://github.com/Reefaq/FlipView). It includes layout tools that you might not need, but the page flipping is implemented using Core Animation layers in the [AFKPageFlipper](https://github.com/Reefaq/FlipView/blob/master/Classes/AFKPageFlipper.h) class.

To implement it yourself:

1. Copy the view's layer contents to an image. (`[layer renderInContext:]`)
2. Add the right side of the image to a new layer's `contents`.
3. Add a rotation `CATransform3D` transform to the layer with perspective. See [Listing 2 in the Core Animation Guide for adding perspective](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/Layers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006082-SW14).